# Offline Maps by Longitude Altitude?

Tags: c#, .net, google-maps, geolocation, gps

I'm trying to create a C# application that downloads maps from some Maps Database (OpenStreetMap, Google Maps, Yahoo Maps)

And then to make an API that show me my location on the downloaded maps without being connected to the internet ...?

I found a lot of examples of google offline maps but i cant find something to show your location on downloaded maps using Longitude and Latitude.

Comment: Caching or extracting content from Google Maps may stay against the Google Maps Terms of Service http://maps.google.com/help/terms_maps.html

Comment: You cannot calculate a position if you only know the Longitude and Altitude.

Comment: @Ramhound you could just use the _edit_ link and make it latitude...

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know the [GMap.Net control](http://greatmaps.codeplex.com/) can use a local cache. So you could populate the cache with the tiles you like and afterwards simply change to cache-only mode.

If you look deeper into code it should also be possible to get some data in and out of the cache by some API. So you could download the tiles once and save them to disk. At startup you'll inject the tiles into the cache and set the mode from the beginning to cache-only.